# Ion DateTime also sends DateTime as UTC (Z)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ionic-framework

My Ionic 3 app uses the ion DateTime field where the user inputs a date.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" [(ngModel)]="scheduled_at"></ion-datetime>
```

This gets then send to my Rails 5 API. The string that arrives at my API endpoint looks like this:

```
"scheduled_at"=>"2018-06-14T23:33:42.939Z"
```

I read that the Z indicates UTC (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/its-about-time-zones). The issue is that the timezone the user enters is not in ZTC but in 'America/Sao_Paulo', so when I parse the string to a DateTime object in Rails and store it to the DB it will always be wrong.

Is there any way to tell the ion DateTime the correct timezone?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, there is no way to do that. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) is an alternative.

In [ionic datatime documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/),

> **Advanced Datetime Validation and Manipulation**
>
> The datetime picker provides the simplicity of selecting an exact
>   format, and persists the datetime values as a string using the
>   standardized ISO 8601 datetime format. However, it's important to note
>   that ion-datetime does not attempt to solve all situtations when
>   validating and manipulating datetime values. **If datetime values need
>   to be parsed from a certain format, or manipulated (such as adding 5
>   days to a date, subtracting 30 minutes, etc.), or even formatting data
>   to a specific locale, then we highly recommend using moment.js to
>   "Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript".**
>   Moment.js has quickly become our goto standard when dealing with
>   datetimes within JavaScript, but Ionic does not prepackage this
>   dependency since most apps will not require it, and its locale
>   configuration should be decided by the end-developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use toLocaleString() string function of Date

```
 myDate: String = new Date().toLocaleString();
```